# javascript / node.js - get object property level

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have an object with multiple child properties:

```
let obj = { a: "a", b: { c: "c", d: { e: "e" } } }
```

how can I get an object property's depth:

eg. "e" property depth is 4 (or 3) `obj.b.d.e`

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Your example is right. You can access them is this way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the total depth of an unknown JSON hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075664/how-to-get-the-total-depth-of-an-unknown-json-hierarchy)

Comment: Count the number of periods in `obj.b.d.e`

Comment: If you know the key, but don't know the path to it: stringify with `JSON.stringify(obj);`, truncate at the key with `json.substring(0, json.indexOf(key))`, and then count the curlys with `.match(new RegExp("\{", "g")) || [];`

Comment: Upon further review - @danh actually has the easiest solution. simply counting the opening curlies and subtracting the closing curlies gave me the depth I was looking for in complex hierarchies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive method initialising `depth` as `1`, using a separate function to check whether something is an actual object (given that almost everything in JS is of type "object").

```js
const obj = { a: "a", b: { c: "c", d: { e: "e" } } }

function isObject(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]';
}

function getDepth(obj, query, depth = 1) {
  if (!isObject(obj)) return 'Not an object';
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (key === query) return `Found ${query} at depth ${depth}`;
    if (isObject(value)) return getDepth(value, query, ++depth);
  }
  return 'No property matching query';
}

console.log(getDepth(obj, 'b'));
console.log(getDepth(obj, 'c'));
console.log(getDepth(obj, 'e'));
```

Comment: So the ask was about getting the depth per property not just the max depth. eg. const `const obj = { a: "a1", b: { x: "x2", y: { z: "z3" }, c: "c1" , d: { e: "e2" } } }`  just returns a max depth not for each property which is what I needed. However, I think `isObject` gave me some ideas on incrementing and decrementing.

Comment: @Rahabib I've updated the answer so the function accepts a query.