# How to getting the depth of the tree object?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, javascript-objects

I have a JSON-like hierarchy of JS objects in the following format:

How can I get object depth? I need count of depth.

**Example data:**

```
{
  t1: 'V1',
  t2: {
    head: 'V2',
    t3: {
      head: 'V3',
      t5: 'V5',
      t6: 'V6',
    },
  },
  t4: {
    head: 'V4',
    t7: 'V7',
    t8: 'V8',
    t9: {
      head: 'V9',
      t10: 'V10',
      t11: 'V11',
      t12: {
        head: 'V12',
        t13: 'V13',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I've found this, much cleaner code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16075976/5214911

The only difference is that I have not one base object but an array of objects as root. How could I simplify the code to spare that extra if and iteration?

**Example data:**

```
const data1 = []; // depth: 0

const data2 = [{}, {}, {}]; // depth: 1

const data3 = [{}, // depth: 5
  {
    "subs": [{
      "subs": [{
        "subs": [{}]
      }, {
        "subs": [{
          "subs": [{}]
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "subs": [{
        "subs": [{}]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {}
];
```

Comment: Please don't repost the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75244459/how-to-get-the-depth-of-a-tree-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the total depth of an unknown JSON hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075664/how-to-get-the-total-depth-of-an-unknown-json-hierarchy) You can use the code from the linked answer with: `console.log(Math.max(...[0, ...data3.map(getDepth)]));`.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the depth of every children and take the maximum value of it.

```js
const
    getDepth = (array = []) =>
        1 + Math.max(0, ...array.map(o => getDepth(o.subs))),
    test = [{}, { subs: [{ subs: [{ subs: [{}] }, { subs: [{ subs: [{}] }] }] }, {subs: [{ subs: [{}] }] }] }, {}],       depth = getDepth(test) - 1; // zero based

console.log(depth);
```